# In Java, thread hangs in SocketRead0, what can I do?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm developing a webcrawler, but often after a short time executing (minutes), some threads stop to do their work. Running a debugger, I found that it stop in SocketRead0.

This occurs when the thread will download the content of a page with a `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()`.

I don't know what causes this, but I think that is associated to the multithreading.

Someone knows how to solve or avoid this?

I'm not using a pool of HttpURLConnection yet beucase I don't know how to do.

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
conn.connect();
CountingInputStream content;

try {
    content = new CountingInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
    //processing of content
    content.close();
    return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Start by posting some code - no one can see what you did, so no one can suggest a fix.

Comment: Is it possible the crawling thread is actually waiting for data from remote server? I'd use NIO for such things.

Comment: @duffymo I added some code. The connection is open to the server, the thread stop in the `conn.getInputStream()`

Comment: I'm developing a webcrawler... with HttpURLConnection. Forget it. As for your question, you can just wait for the connection to timeout or call Thread.interrupt

Comment: @bestsss What you recommend to use?

Comment: @Renato, you need NIO if you are serious, Apache HTTP client will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a socket read timeout on the connection. This will cause it to throw an exception instead of hanging after the specified time period.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int)

Comment: Worked, but the thread was hanging while oppening connection to the server, not while reading, so I used the `setConnectTimeout()`. Very thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The server you're using is probably not sending data when you expect it to, and your thread is blcoked waiting for data.

The original `java.io.*` classes you are using are a *blocking* I/O implementation, which means that methods like `InputStream.read()` will halt the thread if no data is available to read - the call waits until there is data, and if it arrives the method returns.

In Java 1.4, the `java.nio` package was added, which is a *non-blocking* I/O implementation. I recommend you use that if you're using a server that may not serve reliably. [Here are some examples](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/index.html) of how to use nio.

Comment: too much trouble to switch to nio only for timeout. io has timeout setting too.